# failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, mkdir

i have problem with this code :

**form.php**

```
    $dir = date("d-m-y(H-i-s)");
    mkdir('../files/'.$dir, 0755, true);
    mkdir('../files/'.$dir.'/files', 0755, true);
    mkdir('../files/'.$dir.'/imgs', 0755, true);
    mkdir('../files/'.$dir.'/thumb', 0755, true);

  //<input type="hidden" name="folder" value="<?php echo $dir ?>"/>
```

**upload.php**

```
$count = 0;
$DIR = $_POST['folder'];
$imgsDIR  = '../files/'.$DIR.'/imgs/';
$thumbDIR = '../files/'.$DIR.'/thumb';

  foreach ($_FILES['img']['name'] as $filename) 
        {
            $tmp = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'][$count];
            $temp = $imgsDIR.$filename;
            move_uploaded_file($tmp,$temp);
            make_thumb($temp ,$thumbDIR ,150);
            $temp='';
            $tmp='';
            $count++;
        }

function make_thumb($src, $dest, $desired_width) {

$source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);//ok
//some cods
imagejpeg($virtual_image, $dest);//error Permission denied  
}
```

i also tryed `0644` , `0777` but does not work 
and i used  (full control) for this folder

Comment: is files supposed to be made in the root directory of the web site?
Did you try /files instead?
/files is sub of site-root, ./files is for sub of current directory.

Comment: Shouldn't you append a filename to your `$thumbDir` when calling `make_thumb`? `make_thumb($temp, $thumbDir.'/'.$filename, 150);`

Comment: yes i tryed any directory of the web site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append a filename to `$thumbDir` when calling `make_thumb()` or else you will try to store the created thumbnail with the same name as the thumbnail directory:

```
 foreach ($_FILES['img']['name'] as $filename) {
     $tmp = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'][$count];
     $temp = $imgsDIR.$filename;
     move_uploaded_file($tmp, $temp);
     // make sure you have a filename and not only an directory path
     make_thumb($temp, $thumbDIR.'/'.$filename, 150);
     $temp='';
     $tmp='';
     $count++;
 }
```